# Your opinion - GPRS Internet - Mobile

Tags: language-agnostic, gprs

1. Is 8megabytes are a large load if they are transfered via GPRS every day?
2. How large in terms of size (bytes/kbytes) a get request + response is? (eg 200OK)

Comment: Your question should be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

1. Is Equal to R16 per day in my currency.
2. 15
3. Please ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, fastest GPRS is about 296 kbits/sec.  That's 29.5 kbytes/sec.  With that it would take 4.5 minutes to transfer.  So assuming you could get the MAXIMUM speed it wouldn't be so bad and if you were only doing it once per day.

**EDIT**

Please not that speed is considering the best situation and EGPRS (EDGE/2G).  Accroding to the GPRS spec the highest actual GPRS speeds are 80 kbits/sec or 10 kbytes/sec.  Assuming those speeds it would take 13.33~ mins to transfer.